# React native web scrollview snap?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-web

I'm using scrollview with react native web and I am trying to get the scrollview to snap into place however it just scroll like normal. I have tried using these props but it isn't working.

```
horizontal= {true}
decelerationRate={0}
snapToInterval={200} //your element width
snapToAlignment={"center"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this does not seem to be currently implemented :(

Source: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1250

There is always pagingEnabled={true} but this is not exatcly the same thing.